# Monix - Why does this future complete?

Tags: scala, monix

Below is a simple program that awaits a cancellable future. The future should evaluate to wait 20 seconds. I'm trying to demonstrate the 5.second max time bound kicking in. However, the program seems to ignore the 5.second max time bound, and waits for 20 seconds. Does anyone know why this is? Thanks

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.{DateTime, richReadableInstant, richReadableInterval}
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.execution.Scheduler
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await

object TaskRunToFuture extends App {

  def waitTwenty = {
    val start = DateTime.now()
    while ((start to DateTime.now()).millis < 20000) { /** do nothing */ }
   
  }

  val result = Await.result(Task.eval(waitTwenty).runToFuture, 5.seconds)

}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Monix, but I'm guessing your code is just waiting for 5 seconds, while the background task continues to run for 20 seconds because its not interrupted/cancelled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Monix's [Design Summary](https://monix.io/docs/current/eval/task.html#design-summary):

> doesn’t necessarily execute on another logical thread

In your case, you've defined a Task that doesn't inherently have any "async boundaries" that would force Monix to shift to another thread, so when you call `runToFuture` it ends up executing `waitTwenty` on the current thread. Thus, the task has already completed by the time the Future is actually returned, so `Await.result` isn't actually called until the 20 seconds are up.

See [`Task#executeAsync`](https://monix.io/api/3.4/monix/eval/Task.html#executeAsync:monix.eval.Task%5BA%5D) which inserts an async boundary before the task, e.g. `Task.eval(waitTwenty).executeAsync.runToFuture`

Normally this kind of thing isn't an issue since you generally don't want to call any of the `run*` methods except in your application's `main`; instead you'll compose everything in terms of `Task` so your whole app is ultimately one big `Task` that can be run, e.g. as a [`TaskApp`](https://monix.io/api/3.4/monix/eval/TaskApp.html).

```scala
def waitTwenty = {
  println("starting wait...")
  Thread.sleep(20000)
  println("done waiting!")
}

Await.result(Task.eval(waitTwenty).executeAsync.runToFuture, 5.seconds)
```

Outputs

```
waiting...
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Future timed out after [5 seconds]
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait0(Promise.scala:248)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:261)
  at monix.execution.CancelableFuture$Async.result(CancelableFuture.scala:371)
  at scala.concurrent.Await$.$anonfun$result$1(package.scala:201)
  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:62)
  at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:124)
  ... 59 elided
```

Comment: Thank  you, and thanks for making me realize I didn't need that nscala_time stuff either for this example

Comment: No problem! Also note, there's a `Task.sleep` to create a task that just waits, but *without blocking* the current thread like I did in my answer.